# Why do I get a "Thread 1: "-[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000" error

Tags: swift, xcode

I get this error that I am trying to fix but I have to been able to since I am new to swift. If anyone could help me approach the problem or if anyone know how to fix this, please let me know. The error that I get says:

> Thread 1: "`-[__NSCFString count]`: unrecognized selector sent to instance `0x6000`"

This is my code:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

   

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        
        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
                    application,
                    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions
                )
        return true
    }
    
    func application(
            _ app: UIApplication,
            open url: URL,
            options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]
        ) -> Bool {
            ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
                app,
                open: url,
                sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                annotation: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]
            )
        }  

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }

}
```

Comment: `0x6000` is very unlikely to be a normal object address. You most likely have some kind of memory corruption going on. Are you using any unsafe memory APIs?

Comment: Also, the code you've posted here is absolutely not involved. This is clearly not all you code (though you can't reasonably post all of it), and your problem is somewhere else. As Alexander notes, you should of course look for any calls involving the word `Unsafe`. Or things that call into ObjC or C. If that doesn't make it clear, you'll need to add logging or breakpoints all over and see where it is actually failing. If even that doesn't work, you'll start removing parts of your program until the problem goes away. But start with calls to APIs that have `Unsafe` in their name.

Comment: Xcode always switches you to the app delegate when you get this kind of crash. But it is not where the crash _is_. You need to show us the entire _crash log_ (in the Xcode console) and then we can tell you where the problem is.

Comment: @matt Do you know why Xcode does that? (focus the AppDelegate for some kinds of crashes)? Under what conditions does it do that?

Comment: @Alexander it focuses on AppDelegate because `@UIApplicationMain` is the only code of yours that is part of the stack trace.

Comment: @daltonclaybrook Ah, that makes sense. Thanks for clarifying.